# AngularJS: refresh ng-include after insert

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can someone tell me the correct way to refresh an ng-include? 
I've written an application to insert and remove dvd's. The dvd list is displayed as ng-include:

index.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="topdiv">    
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <div ng-include src="'pages/dvd-list.html'"></div>
    </div>  

    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    <div class="col-sm-9 main">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

dvd-list.html

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar" ng:controller="dvdListController">
  <li ng:repeat="dvd in dvdList">
    <a href='#/dvdList/{{ dvd.title }}'>{{ dvd.title }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('dvdManApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/dvdList/:title', {
            templateUrl   : 'pages/dvd-details.html', 
            controller : 'dvdDetailsController'
        });
})

.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {     
    $scope.message = 'Insert content here';

    $scope.addDvd = function () {
        window.location = "#/dvdList/add";
    };
}])

.controller('dvdDetailsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'DataFactory', function($scope, $routeParams, DataFactory) {
    DataFactory.getDVDItem($routeParams.title).success(function(response){$scope.dvd = response;});

    $scope.createDVD = function () {
        DataFactory.insertDVD($scope.dvd).success(function(response){window.alert("Insert OK.");window.location.reload();}).error(function(response){"Insert NOT OK!!"});           
        window.location = "#/";
    };

    $scope.deleteDVD = function () {
        DataFactory.deleteDVD($scope.dvd.title).success(function(response){window.alert("Delete OK.");window.location.reload();}).error(function(response){window.alert("Delete NOT OK!!.");});
        window.location = "#/";
    };

}])

.controller('dvdListController', ['$scope', 'DataFactory', function($scope, DataFactory) {              
     DataFactory.getDVDList().success(function(response) { $scope.dvdList = response.alldvd; }).error(function(result){});       
}]);
```

Now the problem, when I add a new dvd, the ng-include is not refreshed.
How can I perform a refresh without using window.location.reload()?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract your logic for getting/adding the DVDs into a DvdFactory. Then in your ng-included template just use the getter from the DvdFactory to access the list. That way whenever you add/remove from it, your ng-repeat will be updated automatically.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said: <li ng:repeat="dvd in getDvdList()"> but now I don't see anything .....Could it have something to do with the $http.get?

Comment: In your `DvdFactory`, you will have your `$http` call separate. Then the `ng-repeat="dvd in DvdFactory.dvdList"` with the `$http` call populating the dvdList. There will also be methods to add/remove inside the `DvdFactory` that will modify the dvdList there. Make sure to add the `DvdFactory` onto your scope in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to auto-update, but I used an angular value to store my data.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1l7g6HzRuzGZQT5W7X0v?p=info

```
app.controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, movies, $location) {
  function guid() {
    function s4() {
      return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '' + s4() + '' + s4() + '' +
      s4() + '' + s4() + s4() + s4();
  }
  $scope.add = function() {
    var gid = guid();
    movies.push({
      id: gid,
      movie: $scope.name,
      about: $scope.about,
      image: 'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'
    });
    $location.path('/details/' + gid);
  };
});
```

Edit: To answer your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137453/angularjs-refresh-ng-include-after-insert/31141418?noredirect=1#comment50305571_31141418): You are caching data on your client in the form of JavaScript arrays. And if that was your strategy, either the approach I've mentioned or Primms's approach seems fine. (Personally I'd go with the latter).

However if caching is something frowned upon, your alternative is to fetch it from the server on demand. But how do you know when to go to the server?

You would have to rely on promises and events for that.

Comment: thanks for your info. Is this the way it is recommend?